# Access Default User Photo

Tags: templating, users

I'm calling user photo's from my template, but it error's out when trying to obviously call a user photo which is empty. What I'm trying to achieve is

> *if there is no user photo, use the default placeholder image craft supplies*

The problem I'm having trouble getting to the bottom of is, how to access the default user photo?

```
    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="{{ entry.author.getPhoto().url }}" width="100" height="100" alt="{{ entry.author }} Picture">
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the default blank user SVG from the Control Panel on the front-end of the site when there is no photo selected?

If so, it's probably easiest just to copy it from `vendor/craftcms/cms/web/assets/cp/dist/images/user.svg` to a place in your public HTML folder and reference it there.

Something like:

```
{% if entry.author.getPhoto() %}
    {{ entry.author.getPhoto().url }}
{% else %}
    {{ url('path/to/user.svg') }}
{% endif %}
```